# Sorting possibly unstable and general jsfiddle/jquery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a simple sorting algorithm that I was told is possibly unstable. I'm wondering what in the sort is unstable. I have test cases written to test all fields with no issues.

A secondary problem is that jQuery is not appending the rows for some reason (works fine in local and server environments).

http://jsfiddle.net/SucGH/

```
var applyData = function (dataSet) {
    $('#healthplans tbody').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
        var itemRow = '';
        for (item in dataSet[i]) {
            var newItem = dataSet[i][item];
            if (typeof newItem === 'number') newItem = "$" + newItem;
            itemRow += '<td>' + newItem + '</td>';
        }
        $('#healthplans tbody').append('<tr>' + itemRow + '</tr>');
    }
}

var order = '';
var sortDataByField = function (field, newOrder, test) {
    if (!newOrder) order = (order == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    else order = newOrder;
    if (field) {
        jsonData.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (typeof b[field] === 'string') {
                var bfield = b[field].toUpperCase();
                var afield = a[field].toUpperCase();
                if (bfield < afield) return (order == 'asc') ? -1 : 1;
                if (bfield > afield) return (order == 'asc') ? 1 : -1;
                return 0;
            } else if (typeof b[field] === 'number') {
                if (order == 'desc') return b[field] - a[field]
                else if (order == 'asc') return a[field] - b[field]
                return 0;
            }
        });
        if (!test) {
            applyData(jsonData);
        }

    } else {
        return 'Field and/or order not properly defined';
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it's off-topic to ask to fix a bug or something like that (Read the FAQ for more details http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The rest of the question is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the built-in `sort` of `Array`, which is not guaranteed to be stable per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You will have to write your own sort algorithm from scratch.

Other than that,

- It is considered better form to have a single comma separated `var` statement
- Calling `append()` inside a loop gives poor performance, just collect everything in a string, and call `append()` once
- You could cache `$('#healthplans tbody')` since you call it more than once
- You should not skip the newline after an `if` statement
- You should consider using `hasOwnProperty` when using `for (item in dataSet[i])`
- You did not declare `item` with `var`
- You call too many things `item`, I am assuming that the property in dataSet is more of itemId ?
- All that gives this :

  ```
  var applyData = function (dataSet) {
      var i,
          itemId
          item,
          itemRow, 
          html = '';            
          $table = $('#healthplans tbody'),

      $table.empty();
      for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
          itemRow = '';
          for (itemId in dataSet[i]) {
              item= dataSet[i][itemId];
              if (typeof item=== 'number') 
                item= '$' + item;
              itemRow += '<td>' + item+ '</td>';
          }
          html += '<tr>' + itemRow + '</tr>';
      }
      $table.append( html );        
  }
  ```

I did not comment on the `sort` function, since that most likely will be throw away.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about sort and I've been using it all this time :) For this particular set of data, I don't think it mattered, but at least I know what they meant now. I particularly don't tend to go with the comma list, but that's just me. I totally forgot var to scope the item down, oops! The dataset is really a dataset, it's an array of objects with properties. The newline skipped accidentally when I pasted this here from jslint.

The hints for append and caching the elements are good catches.

Thanks, this list is really great and shows where I could improve things.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why append is not working in the jsfiddle example, would you? (and is working on local/server)

Comment: I would, id is `healthPlans`, jQuery looks for `healthplans`

Comment: Yet another reason I should have just cached the element :)